# Graph that connect between two groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph-theory

I created a program that accepts two groups of sentences as input and makes some comparison between them.
Each sentence from group 'A' has one or more matching sentences in group 'B', and sentence from group 'B' can match more than one sentence in 'A'.
Each relationship has a numeric value.
I'm trying to create a graph describing these connections for the purpose of easy visualization of the connections.
I thought to create a bipartite graph so that each arc has value, Somthing like the example image below (group A on the left and group B on the right) ([from here](https://rgmining.github.io/fraudar/)).

I am looking for other ideas or maybe an library that I can use for it.
Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bi-partite graph makes a lot of sense for this and if you use the `networkX` library you can easily create one. Assuming you have your elements in `A` and `B` and a list containing the edges

```
A = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
B = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']
edges = [('a1', 'b1', 0.5), ('a1', 'b2', 0.3), ('b3', 'a4', 0.1)]
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(A], bipartite=0) # Add the node attribute "bipartite"
G.add_nodes_from(B, bipartite=1)
G.add_weighted_edges_from(edges)
```

Note that this is just a normal graph and and the only way to tell it is bi-partite is through the property `bipartite`. If you need to do stuff like projecting the graph or accessing only one side then there is more on that in the [networkX documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.bipartite.html).

Comment: Thank you, I used this solution and adapte it to my needs. Another thing, I tried to add the weight of each arc and to show it on the graph but I didnwt find solution for this. Any help?

Comment: OK I figured it out

Comment: The weight should be the number in the triple `(node1, node2, weight)`